# Does core-js polyfill or does it always replace the function?

Tags: polyfills, babel-polyfill

I have a react project that needs to support older browsers and we're using things like array.find() and array.map(). I see that our project already has core-js in the node_modules folder, so it would be nice to use it rather than adding another package to the project.

If I import like this:

```
import 'core-js/fn/array/find';
```

as was suggested in this response: http://discuss.babeljs.io/t/why-does-array-prototype-find-not-work-with-babel-preset-es2015/46/4 does that polyfill or will it replace the array.find function that may already exist? If it will replace the existing function is there any performance issues or other reasons why you wouldn't want to use this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`core-js` always replaces the functions you import.

There can be problems with that, that one I ran in to was trying to import the full library in code loaded by a framework that loads `zone.js`, which breaks `zone.js` by replacing the Promises that `zone.js` has already replaced.

So now I use `core-js` to polyfill individual functions by doing things like this:

```
if( ! Array.prototype.includes ) { require( "core-js/fn/array/includes" ); }
```

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73444026/1158376

Comment: I'm not actively working with JavaScript now, so I can't conveniently run the experiment again; at the time core-js was replacing the already-present Promise implementation.  Maybe the feature detection misfired, maybe it thinks zone.js is broken, maybe Angular was doing something weird, etc.  The documentation isn't clear on whether it does detection when you require e.g. `actual` vs one specific method.  Or maybe things have just changed in the 5 years since.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> By default, core-js sets polyfills only when they are required. That means that core-js checks if a feature is available and works correctly or not and if it has no problems, core-js use native implementation.

> But sometimes core-js feature detection could be too strict for your case. For example, Promise constructor requires the support of unhandled rejection tracking and @@species.

> Sometimes we could have inverse problem - knowingly broken environment with problems not covered by core-js feature detection.

> For those cases, we could redefine this behaviour for certain polyfills:

```
const configurator = require('core-js/configurator');

configurator({
  useNative: ['Promise'],                                 // polyfills will be used only if natives completely unavailable
  usePolyfill: ['Array.from', 'String.prototype.padEnd'], // polyfills will be used anyway
  useFeatureDetection: ['Map', 'Set'],                    // default behaviour
});

require('core-js/actual');
```

> It does not work with some features. Also, if you change the default behaviour, even core-js internals may not work correctly.

*Source:* https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#configurable-level-of-aggressiveness